# odin , slowdowns after upgrade

Tags: odin

after the update of yesterday 27th october odin has become very slow both at startup and in the use of applications.
Does anyone have the same problems as me?
I have an Intel® Core™ i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz Dual-Core Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
Memory: 3.3 GiB
Disk: 112.8 GB.

Comment: Yes, very slow on boot. Just black screen and a cursor visible for a very long time before it starts :-(

Comment: I had the same issue for the last 2 days or so. Looking at dmesg it seems to have been related to a dbus error. The latest pantheon update (from this morning) seems to have fixed the issue for me. Logon to desktop time is now back to a second or so.

Comment: same problem as mine, I have to wait about 2 minutes for the startup, before it was instantaneous

Comment: how did you do to update pantheon, i have slowdowns even using the browser and other programs i think it is a problem related to the new kernel. I am annoyed, reinstalling everything because it took me a long time and the operating system worked much better than in previous versions. a pity!!!
Reluctantly I will switch to xubuntu